# Clean datatable when new data are loaded

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I'd like to load a table from a file, make some computations (ie. sum elements of two columns) when I click a button and show the results into a datatable. Easy. However, every time I load a new file, I'd like to clean the previous results and not show them, otherwise, it is confusing whether they are the results of the new or the old ones.
Here's what I tried. but I didn't succeeed on it...
example table: tab.csv

```
x;A;B
x1;1;0
x2;2;1
x3;1;1
x4;5;2
x5;3;3
```

code: ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(""),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(fluidRow(
    fileInput("table", "Choose CSV File"),
    actionButton("BUTCS", "Compute sum"),
    dataTableOutput("tablesum")
  ))
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  user <- new.env()
  user$table    <- NULL
  user$tablesum <- NULL

  observe({
    if(is.null(input$table)){return()}
    tablefilecsv <- input$table
    user$table  <- read.csv2(tablefilecsv$name, header = TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$table, {
    if(is.null(input$table)){return()}
    user$tablesum <- NULL
  })

  output$tablesum <- renderDataTable(
  {
    if(is.null(input$BUTCS)){return()}
    d <- user$table
    user$tablesum <- data.frame(x=d$x, sum=(d$A+d$B))
  }, options = list(paging = FALSE,searching = FALSE))
})
```

Comment: first what i think, you need to use reactive :`user <- reactiveValues(table=NULL,tablesum=NULL)`

Comment: first of all. thanks! then, I'm not big on `reactiveValues` and probably I should but as far as I know, I then need also a `isolate` command. I'll check it out.

Comment: no. I'm sorry but it seems not to clean and refresh automatically. i don't know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, i think it is what you want

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    user <- reactiveValues(table= NULL,  tablesum= NULL)
    observeEvent(input$table, {
       if(is.null(input$table)){
        return()
      }else{
        tablefilecsv <- input$table
        user$table  <- read.csv2(tablefilecsv$datapath ,header = TRUE)
        output$tablesum <- renderDataTable(NULL)
      }
    })

    observeEvent(input$BUTCS,{
      output$tablesum <- renderDataTable({ 
        d <- user$table
        user$tablesum <- data.frame(x=d$x, sum=(d$A+d$B))
      }, options = list(paging = FALSE,searching = FALSE))
    })

  })
```

**Option using reactive functional** ( added by @Stefano)

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    tablefilecsv <- input$table
    table <- read.csv2(tablefilecsv$name, header=TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$table,{
    output$tablesum <- renderDataTable(NULL)
  })

  observeEvent(input$BUTCS,{
    output$tablesum <- renderDataTable({
    d <- data()
    tablesum <- cbind.data.frame(x=d$x, sum=(d$A+d$B))
  }, options = list(paging=FALSE, searching=FALSE))
  })

})
```

Comment: once again thanks a lot! it works perfectly. yesterday I also tried some other ways but I didn't succeeed. I was just wondering if it is possible to get the same result by using `reactive` rather than `reactiveValues` (it seems more "elegant"). I'll work on it and in case, I'll let you know. anyway, this one is running well! thanks!

Comment: may be this is `reactive` variant `shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    data=reactive({
      input$table
      tablefilecsv <- input$table
      table  <- read.csv2(tablefilecsv$datapath ,header = TRUE)
    })
   
    observeEvent(input$table, {
       if(is.null(input$table)){
        return()
      }else{
        output$tablesum <- renderDataTable(NULL)
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$BUTCS,{
      output$tablesum <- renderDataTable(
{ 
  d <- data()
  tablesum <- data.frame(x=d$x, sum=(d$A+d$B))
}, options = list(paging = FALSE,searching = FALSE))
    })

  })`